# Remove options from Kendo Grid filter

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I try to remove an item from dropdown of Kendo grid filter. But it is still rendered. How can I reach such behaviour?

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "someDate", type: "date" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { someDate: "2016-3-29"},
    { someDate: "2016-3-30"}
  ],
  filterable: {
    extra: true,
    operators: {
      date: {
        gte: "Is after or equal to",
        lte: "Is before or equal to"
      }
    }
  },
  filterMenuInit: function(e) {
    e.container.find("select:eq(0)>option")[1].remove();
    e.container.find("select:eq(1)>option")[1].remove();
    e.container.find("select:eq(2)>option")[0].remove();
  }
});
```

Link on [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EPegi/4).
Please help.

**EDITED**:
I need two complex filters for dates. In the first filter I need only "Is after or equal to", then "AND", and in the second filter I need only "Is before or equal to". I try to do this by removing "Is before or equal to" from the first dropdown and "Is after or equal to" from the second one.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of removing you can add only what you want

```
  filterable: {
                 extra: false,
                 operators: {
                 string: {
                  startswith: "Starts with",
                  eq: "Is equal to",
                  neq: "Is not equal to"
                          }
                        }
              },
```

Comment: It will not help me. I need two complex filters for dates. In the first filter I need only "Is after or equal to", then "AND", and in the second filter I need only "Is before or equal to". I can't do this this way.

Comment: I have added some details for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the kendoDropDownList object, then remove the item from the dataSource; I have updated your [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/EPegi/6)

```
<script>
    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        columns: [
            { field: "name" }
        ],
        dataSource: [
            { name: "Jane Doe"},
            { name: "John Doe"}
        ],
        filterable: true,
        filterMenuInit: function(e) {
        if (e.field == "name") {
            var filter1 = e.container.find("select:eq(0)").data("kendoDropDownList");
            var filter2 = e.container.find("select:eq(2)").data("kendoDropDownList");
            filter1.dataSource.remove(filter1.dataSource.at(0));
            filter1.select(0);
            filter2.dataSource.remove(filter2.dataSource.at(0));
            filter2.select(0);
          }
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works when grid is loaded the first time. But if you press the Clear button the first dropdown will be reset to empty value. I guess it set the default value which is removed.

Comment: This is technically a hack since it is setting the value of a member that is intended to be private... But it works...
    ...
    filter1._initial = 'lte';

http://dojo.telerik.com/EPegi/11

Answer (score -1):

> see the below example use filterable: false in field section to remove filter from column.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name", filterable: false },
    { field: "age" }
  ],
  filterable: true,
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane", age: 30 }, { name: "John", age: 33 }]
});
</script>
```